# Java Null Pointer Exception - Stack Trace Null

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, jit

I am running an application in eclipse. It spawns 6 threads. One of the threads gives an exception:

```
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The stack trace is: `null`.

I am using eclipse. And cannot go through the steps (the debug panel gives a very top level function trace of where exception occurs which is not useful to get to the root cause).

How can I debug this exception?

I am kind of Java newbie (though experienced with C++) and may have missed some important information.

---

Here is some relevant code:

```
import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader;

Cache<BubbleKey, List<BlockData>> thecache;
// Above is initialized somewhere.. bit complex and code distributed across various file

//Somewhere else
List<BlockData>> __ll = thecache.getUnchecked(keydata);
```

Above is what is causing it. The keydata is properly initialized. It could be in the lookup/comparing the keys functions but I cannot get there as there is no stack trace.

---

<strike>Some more! On some runs, I am getting more debug output. Still don't know how to analyze it though.</strike>

Below exception is a different one, occurring at later stages, after the above exception has occurred 3-4 times in the program. For the above exception, as I mentioned, there is never any stack trace.

```
at com.google.common.cache.CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputedUncheckedException.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:3305) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:3441) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.compute(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2322) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.CustomConcurrentHashMap$Segment.getOrCompute(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2291) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.CustomConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:3802) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.ComputingCache.get(ComputingCache.java:46) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.cache.AbstractCache.getUnchecked(AbstractCache.java:49) ~[guava-10.0.1.jar:na]
 (at myfunction.... )
```

Comment: It'd be nice to see some code that's relevant to this. Could be a number of things.

Comment: sounds to be a null pointer exception swallowed by the thread pool. Give us some code as Austin resquest !

Comment: added sample code. could be incomplete, but confused at this point myself what else could be relevant :)

Comment: You need [locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) to modify an object used by several threads at once.

Comment: Be carefull, getunchecked on guava cache is deprecated. Can we see your cache loader or cache builder implementaton ?

Comment: m0skit0 guava cache is thread safe and suports concurrency

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like you experience the error running in debug, have you tried setting some break points and seeing if you can trace down exactly where the error is coming from?  If it's a multi-threaded application, you should be thinking about ways that your could be accessing uninitialized data that otherwise wouldn't be possible.